# How to make IntelliJ reference a local project for a dependency?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Working in a multi-module Maven project, call it "app." I need to work on the source of one of the dependencies, call it "lib", and be able to easily test/debug "app" against my changes in "lib."

In Eclipse this is an option for its Maven and Gradle plug-ins, and is obvious since Eclipse doesn't bind the concepts of "workspace" and "project" as tightly as IntelliJ does. When I cloned the repo for "lib", IntelliJ offered to create a new project for it, but how do I force "app" to use the local working copy of "lib" for compilation and runtime?

To put it another way, can IntelliJ basically encapsulate doing `build install` on "lib" behind the scenes so that "app" uses the updated (snapshot) of it?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious, cleanest choice would be to combine the two projects into a common Maven multi-pom project. If that is something you can't do (perhaps the projects belong to different teams etc.), then I could imagine you could fake it by using symlinks.

Create a wrapper project with just a pom file and two modules. Instead of folders for the modules, use symbolic links to the actual file locations. Obviously the reactor root pom would not be the parent pom.

Now open the wrapper pom as IntelliJ project.

I don't know if this works, but it's worth a try.